# Entanglement swapping and Bell state analyzer

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement

In entanglement swapping where AB from two entangled pairs AC and BD are projected into Bell state by Bell state measurement (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_state#Bell_state_measurement) on A and B then CD would be orthogonal to AB. So if AB are sent through such Bell state analyzer that distinguishes psi and phi states and sends them to different outputs X and Y would CD still be orthogonal to AB?

Comment: What is "joint Bell measurement"? Please make your question as clear and self-contained as possible.

Comment: What do you mean "distinguishes psi and phi states"?